# KeyError: 'optimizer_state_dict'

Tags: python, pytorch

I tried to use a pre-trained model on another dataset to resume training on my dataset with the same code, but there is error arise after downloading the model and running main.py to load model

This error arises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 348, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 299, in main
    model, optimizer, epoch_idx, ckpt_dict = load_model(args.model_path, model, optimizer)
  File "/.../lipreading/utils.py", line 170, in load_model
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
KeyError: 'optimizer_state_dict'
```

and this is the [GitHub link](https://github.com/mpc001/Lipreading_using_Temporal_Convolutional_Networks#model-zoo) from which I used their code and pre-trained model.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to key not existed in Python dictionary (in your case will be your checkpoint doesn't have any key named 'optimizer_state_dict'). You can print your dictionary keys using the .keys() method and check if your checkpoint contain 'optimizer_state_dict'.